# Jquery Dragable help disabled when clicked

Tags: jquery

i am currently use Draggable in Jquery i am trying to make it so when you click on a div it will disable you from draging it i have the follow code be it seems to not work can anyone lead me in the right direction please

```
selected_div = $("input#selected_div").val();

 $("#68").draggable({ 
          containment: 'parent',
if(selected_div == 68){
          disabled: true,
}else{
          disabled: false,
}
          handle: 'drag_border',
          drag: function(e, ui) {
                 var top = ui.position.top;
                 var left = ui.position.left;
                 $("input#tuPBd0hm_top").val(top);
                 $("input#tuPBd0hm_left").val(left);
                 $("#top").html(top);
                 $("#left").html(left);
}
});
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var selected_div = $("input#selected_div").val();
var isDraggable;
if(selected_div == "68") isDraggable = true;
else isDraggable = false

$("#a68").draggable({ 
          containment: 'parent',
          disabled: isDraggable,
          handle: 'drag_border',
          drag: function(e, ui) {
                 var top = ui.position.top;
                 var left = ui.position.left;
                 $("input#tuPBd0hm_top").val(top);
                 $("input#tuPBd0hm_left").val(left);
                 $("#top").html(top);
                 $("#left").html(left);
          }
});
```

And if you want to be able to disable or enable the div from being draggable after the page has been loaded then look at [jquery Draggable API](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and click the Methods tab

```
$("#a68").draggable("disable");
$("#a68").draggable("enable");
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

An ID in html must begin with a letter, so "#68" really shouldn't select anything. Try putting a letterr a-z in the front of the ID.